# How do I apply a binary/Boolean mask to filter a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How do I use a binary mask like so in pure Kotlin? (without kotlin-numpy)

```
Input:  [   2,     3,     5,    7,    11] len=5
Mask:   [true, false, false, true, false] len=5

Output: [   2,                  7       ] len=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are [**extension functions**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for the **List** type. Both versions are equivalent:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.applyMask(mask: List<Boolean>): List<T> =
        this.filterIndexed { i, _ -> mask.getOrElse(i) { false } }
```

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.applyMask(mask: List<Boolean>): List<T> =
        this.zip(mask).filter { it.second }.map { it.first }
```

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a = listOf(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
    val mask = listOf(true, false, false, true, false)
    println(a.applyMask(mask))  // [2, 7]
}
```

Above code will take the shorter list as reference if the lengths are mismatched.

With explicit checking for **mismatched lengths**:

```kotlin
fun <T> List<T>.applyMask(mask: List<Boolean>): List<T> =
        if (this.size != mask.size)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Lists must be of equal size")
        else
            this.filterIndexed { i, _ -> mask[i] }
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Lists must be of equal size
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to xjcl's answer (upvoted), that you can also make use of functions such as [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) and [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) for arguably nicer syntax:

```
fun <T> List<T>.applyMask(mask: List<Boolean>): List<T> = run {
    require(size == mask.size) { "Lists must be of equal size" }
    filterIndexed { i, _ -> mask[i] }
}
```

Comment: Ah, `require` also throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, interesting!

Comment: I'm also not sure whether to use `getOrElse` or just `get`/`[]` since we explicitly check the size. I guess this only matters if the List gets modified in another thread, but how can I handle this odd case?

Comment: It's not a mutable list, so it shouldn't get modified. Right, just `mask[i]` is nicer. I've updated this version. I didn't think about the implementation in detail, there may be a better way to do it, I was just focussing on the syntax (and even that's personal preference!) :-)

Comment: Ah yes, a List isn't mutable, I was still too much in the Java mindset haha!